# Excel VBA, multi parameter filter to return row ID

Tags: algorithm, excel, search, multiple-columns, vba

I currently have an algorithm that manipulates data on sheet 24 in my excel workbook.  I have 3 integers, a, b, and c, that come from data on sheet 24, and I need to use them to return a unique row ID on sheet 14.  A, B, and C, each represent their corresponding Column (range) on sheet 14 IE: Int a from sheet 24 is in column A on sheet 14.  Int b in column b, and c in c.  The numbers combined will always return a singular row ID from 14, in the case, integer row.  I'm having a hard time writing a statement with Filter, evaluate, and a bunch of other Excel functions.  Does anyone know how to launch a script from an algorithm executing on one sheet and just pull a row ID in sheet 14 using its' resulting three search numbers for a,b,c?

```
row = Sheets("Physical Disk Details").Columns("A").Find(what:=a, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) * Sheets("Physical Disk Details").Columns("B").Find(what:=b, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) * Sheets("Physical Disk Details").Columns("C").Find(what:=c, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please add the code you have written to your question so we can help you get it working.

Comment: The question is quite clear.  I want to SELECT RowID FROM Sheet14 WHERE Sheet14.ColumnA = a AND Sheet14.ColumnB = b AND Sheet14.ColumnC = c.  I don't have a VBA example.  Nothing I found does anything at all.  a,b,c being integers returned by my algorithm.  So 0, 1, and 2, for example.  Sheet14 has column A,B,C, and they have numbers.  I want to select the rowID that has 0,1,2 in it.  Or in this case, return the numbers given from my algorithm, a,b, and c.

Comment: I suggest checking out the DB functions for Excel formulas: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/database-functions-reference-HP010079180.aspx specifically `DGET()` may be what you could use for this.

Comment: DGET doesn't return rowID.

Comment: I updated my question with a code example.  This formula returns a number, but it is not the correct row number.  I want to find the row where int a in Column a on sheet("Physical Drive Details"), int b in Column B, and c in Column C.  The code examples on MSDN and other sites are confusing and nothing does what I want.

Comment: Do some meta-programming. Plan out the process in "broad strokes" then write the code to accomplish it. 1) You need to look at one row at a time so you will need a [**loop**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx) that contains the code you want executed for each row. 2) [**For each**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) row, [**if**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) 3 specific truths are found on this row you've found the answer. (`If a=x And b=y And c=z Then`) 3) Announce the row # or save it for use in a next step.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I was also thinking it may be easier to do this project in VB.NET and write an external .exe that processes my xlsx file for me.  I can put my entire page 14 with columns A,B, and C in a dataset and run a SQL query against it.  I was writing VBA for end-users hoping it would be easier, but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Function will return the first row number that is found to exactly match what is provided for a,b, and c. It demonstrates one of the simplest Range iteration and If/Then tests that forms the foundation of most data pattern searching subroutines you will find for Excel VBA. There are ways to streamline this code but it demonstrates the basic principle.

If you read every line of this code and understand what all of it does you can use the principles to accomplish most tasks even vaguely similar to it.

```
Function GetRowNumberByABCMatch(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer) As Integer
    Dim lastRowInDataSet As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    'get last row containing data in column 1
    lastRowInDataSet = Sheets("Physical Disk Details").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'i = current row number, start at row 1
    For i = 1 To lastRowInDataSet
        If Sheets("Physical Disk Details").Range("A" & i).Value = a _
                And Sheets("Physical Disk Details").Range("B" & i).Value = b _
                And Sheets("Physical Disk Details").Range("C" & i).Value = c Then
            'all fields match, return the current row number
            GetRowNumberByABCMatch = i
            'stop processing and return because we found a single match
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    'didn't find a matching row, return -1
    GetRowNumberByABCMatch = -1
End Function
```

Comment: This worked with some modification.  I didn't think about calling for Sheets(x).Range(x).Value directly.  The changes I made were to the function's parameter requirements: Function GetRowNumberByABCMatch(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer) As Integer

Comment: I converted the numeric strings, a, b, c to integers.  Variant has been giving me issues, so I had to make sure I lined up my datatypes perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for yet another VBA save.